# Add automatically an html code for every video in the blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have many video in the blog, with this classic code:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SlHHS7IC7M0?rel=0" width="640"></iframe>
```

Now i want to transform the code above into this automatically, for every post:

```
<div id="wr">
<div class="trigger open"><a href="#">Open</a></div>
<div class="cnt">
<div class="flex-video widescreen"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SlHHS7IC7M0?rel=0" width="640"></iframe></div>
</div></div>
```

How can i do that in jQuery?

Jsfiddle file: https://jsfiddle.net/zzq91smv/2/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this into your doc ready function:

```
    var template =  '<div class="wr">'+
                    '<div class="trigger open"><a href="#">Open</a></div>'+
                    '<div class="cnt">'+
                    '<div class="flex-video widescreen"></div>'+
                    '</div></div>';

    $('iframe').each(function(ind, ele){
        var $ele = $(ele);
        $ele.after(template);
        $ele.next('.wr').find('.flex-video').append($ele);
    });
```

[**See it in action here**](https://jsfiddle.net/zzq91smv/5/)

Comment: Ted, it's a realy good solution! But in this case i must add the:

<div class="fiddlewrap">

for each post :(

Comment: @supap My bad--updated answer and fiddle to reflect. That was just something i added while messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)?

```
var length = 3;
for (var i=0; i<length; i+=1) {
    $(document.body).append('<div id="wr"><div class="trigger open"><a href="#">Open</a></div><div class="cnt"><div class="flex-video widescreen"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/SlHHS7IC7M0?rel=0" width="640"></iframe></div></div></div>');
}
```